# Why does this simple shell loop stall and start consuming massive amounts of memory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

A friend of mine known for inhumane treatment of machines wanted to stress their CPU, and so wrote a one-liner like this:

```
for z in {1..100000000};do num1=$(($z * $z)) && echo $num1;done
```

When executed, this loop just sits with no output, and a quick look at `top` shows bash consuming massive amounts of memory (**gigabytes** after a few minutes).

As written, I'd expect this process to run sequentially - as in, pass in the `z` variable, calculate it, echo the result, repeat.

Instead, trying this with smaller upper bounds makes it look as if everything is calculated *up front*, and then dumped to the screen *en masse*. As in, it sits for a moment doing the calculations, then does the `echo`'s all at once.

Why does this loop behave this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-iterate-over-a-variable-range-of-numbers-in-bash/), the range operator builds the range (creates an array of integers) before letting you do things to it such as iterating over it. You may be better off with a while loop:

```
 z=1 ; while [[ $z -le 100000000 ]] ; do num1=$(($z * $z)) && echo $num1 ; z=$(($z + 1)) ; done
```

(Although this is unlikely to really stress a CPU as the echo causes some relief. My own system only reaches about 30% utilization while running this.)